# Select Count Outer Joins and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ud.firstname + ' ' + ud.lastname, 
    COUNT(a.createdDate) AS ActivityCount, 
    au.LastActivityDate
FROM 
    dbo.aspnet_Users au 
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserDetails ud 
    ON au.UserId = ud.AspNetUserId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.audit a 
    ON au.LoweredUserName = a.username
WHERE 
    (
        au.LoweredUserName IN ('u1', 'u2', 'u3')
    ) 
AND a.createdDate > '2012-09-18'
GROUP BY ud.firstname + ' ' + ud.lastname, au.LastActivityDate
ORDER BY au.LastActivityDate DESC
```

But let's say that `u1` and `u3` doesn't have any activity since the `2012-09-18` -- then the result only contains `u2`.

I thought the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` made sure that I get all records from `aspnet_Users` -- but I guess this is due to the seconds condition in my `WHERE` clause filtering another table...

What do I need to change in order to get all the specified users, and then a zero as ActivityCount if no data exists for the given period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I guess this is due to the seconds condition in my WHERE clause filtering another table...

Right, the condition on `createdDate` in `WHERE` clause is suppressing the records from `dbo.audit`. You can move that to the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` condition list to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ud.firstname + ' ' + ud.lastname,
    sum(case when a.createdDate is null then 0 else 1 end) AS ActivityCount, 
    au.LastActivityDate
FROM 
    dbo.aspnet_Users au 
    INNER JOIN dbo.UserDetails ud 
    ON au.UserId = ud.AspNetUserId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.audit a 
    ON au.LoweredUserName = a.username
WHERE 
    (au.LoweredUserName IN ('u1', 'u2', 'u3')) 
AND (a.createdDate > '2012-09-18' or a.createdDate is null)
GROUP BY 
    ud.firstname + ' ' + ud.lastname,
    au.LastActivityDate
ORDER BY au.LastActivityDate DESC
```

Comment: This yields the same results as the initial query I posted.